# How can I route to another component when changing the url?

Tags: angular, routes

I want to create a simple routing for the app.
My problem is that when I change the url to .../myComponent.
The Component is rendered but together with the context of another Component referenced in app.component.html
However I like to navigate "away" from the main Component to the actual component so I only see the context of this component.

It seems very simple however I stuck here for a while and not quite understand the problem.
I think the implementation is not correct since with using router-outlet in the app.component.html it will rendered in this place..

```
    {
        path: 'myComponent', component: myComponent
    },
]

@NgModule({
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'}),
],
....
```

app.component.html

```
<other-selector></other-selector>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

MyComponent

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.navigate(['/myComponent']);

  }

}
```

So my goal is simply to render myComponent when changing url to localhost:..../myComponent

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: can refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-resolves-full-example ..

Comment: This looks good but I actually want to change the url and render only the component without main menu page.

Comment: based on what you showed, it is ```other-selector```is is your main menu ?

Comment: Yes other selector is the main menu

Comment: You may also decide to disable the "other-selector" with a *ngIf whenever the component route is activated

Comment: I found something else: I defined the other selector which is the main menu as "Home-Component" and used in the app.component.html only the router-outlet in this way when loading the page, the main menu is displayed and when changing the url the other component is rendered

Comment: could you reproduced this on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kgqr1c?file=src/app/main-component/main-component.component.html Sure:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an `*ngIf` directive to show and hide your app component when you redirected to `myComponent`.You need to check the requested url using `angular routerEvent`,and you can set the boolean value based on your condition to the variable.

**app.component.ts**

```
   constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.showOtherComponent = event.url !== '/myComponent';
      }
    });
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-main-component *ngIf="showOtherComponent"></app-main-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-creagl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**reference**:

1. [Angular - RouterEvent](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart)